# WinRT how do you dynamically add a Triangle to a canvas

Tags: c#, geometry, winrt-xaml

I would like to dynamically add a Triangle to my canvas.  I can do this but only in one very specific way that does not work for my application.  What I would like to do is supply a point and a size and get back a triangle.

```
         var poly = shape as Polygon;
         Polygon p = new  Polygon
        {
            //Width = size, 
            //Height = size,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All,
            RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform()
        };

         int w = 200;
         int h = 200;

        Point start = new Point(400, 200);
        var right = new Point(start.X + w, start.Y);
        var top = new Point(start.X + (w / 2), start.Y - (h));

        poly.Points.Add(point);
        poly.Points.Add(right);
        poly.Points.Add(top);
        poly.Points.Add(point);
```

Then I add the shape to my canvas child controls and and set the X Y on the shapes RenderTransform.  Nothing appears.  If however I just do this:

```
        Polygon p = new  Polygon
        {
            //Width = size,
            //Height = size,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All,
            RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform()
        };

         p.Points.Add(new Point(300, 200));
         p.Points.Add(new Point(400, 125));
         p.Points.Add(new Point(400, 275));
         p.Points.Add(new Point(300, 200));
```

It renders a Triangle just fine.  However if you supply a width and height to the above code it will stop rendering.

Can I just create a triangle of a certain size, without having to set actual points on the canvas at first, much like you do an Ellipse or a Rectangle?

Comment: Look at my examples in your previous question. They're all MVVM based and use DataBinding, instead of this less-practical procedural code approach.

Comment: I went ahead and took the bait and made an MVVM based example.  I would love to know how exactly through MVVM you are able to place random shapes (Circles and Rectangles for the moment) on the screen at various places without using RenderTransform.  I'm bound to a collection of shapes just fine.   But I see no way to allow me to specify Location!

Comment: your Data Items should have an `X` and `Y` property. You can also add a `PointCollection` and have your `Path.Data` in the `DataTemplate` bound to this collection or something.

Comment: What do you actually put in the <DataTemplate> though?  I only get my shapes rendered if I don't have that section?  If my collection contains Ellipses or shapes that I are going to be added Im not sure what Element I would put there?

Comment: your collection should not contain Ellipses or Shapes. See my examples. You need to abstract data away from UI and use DataTemplates to represent data on screen.

Comment: I can abstract the shape data away but then my question is how do I translate that into a non static shape?  I can't just have a couple of <Ellipse /> or <Rectangle /> tags in the <DataTemplate> waiting to be filled in.  I guess I should elaborate on what I'm trying to do.  Its a shape matching game for my daughter.  Each level puts a certain number of Shape pairs on the screen.  Each Pair consists of a Hole and a Peg of the same size and color.  Dragging the correct peg to the correct hole is a match.  Each level has different numbers, sizes, shapes.

Comment: Given the constraints above, I am not sure in an MVVM model how to dynamically create different numbers of different shape types each time.  I can easily stick some static shapes Ellispes and Rectangles in.  I don't see an actual <Shape> tag that I can use to bind to then say, "you're an ellipse", "you're a square". Hmmm... unless maybe I switch to always just using a Polygon and try to use the data to shape it the way I want.   All that said however I still end up back at my origional problem which is this:

Comment: Once the polygon is added to the Canvas I have a very difficult time accurately getting its correct X, Y.  I only have this issue with Polygons.  Canvas.GetTop and GetLeft, and even the RenderTransforms are either 0 or wrong.

Comment: did you look at my examples? there is a base class that has the `X` and `Y`, which are then bound to the screen coordinates. Then you can subclass as many times as you need and create specific DataTemplates for the derived classes.